Nothing happens when trying to create a MongoDB database through a Node.js file
I am following W3Schools.com's 'Node.js MongoDB' tutorial. My action.js file contains the following code:
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";

mongo.connect(url, function (err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database created!");
  db.close();
});

When I try to run the file using node action.js, nothing happens. Even after going through several forums I can't figure out what is going on.
This is the same question but at least that person is getting some error, which I'm not.
Terminal screenshot after executing Node.js command
mongod --version
db version v8.0.1
Build Info: {
    "version": "8.0.1",
    "gitVersion": "fcbe67d668fff5a370e2d87b9b1f74bc11bb7b94",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "tcmalloc-gperf",
    "environment": {
        "distmod": "windows",
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}
mongosh --version
2.3.2

I tried changing the //localhost:27017 to 127.0.0.1:27017 as lots of other solutions have mentioned but it didn't make any difference.

do you have an error, otherwise this code looks correct, try adding a record to any collection. If you don't have an error than that should create the db, the collection and the record.

I'm not getting any error. I tried manually creating the 'mydb' database using MongoDB Compass and then creating a collection through node.js but the same thing happens in the terminal with that also.

Try instead this script which works:

const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const client = new MongoClient(url);

// Database Name
const dbName = 'mydb';

async function main() {
    // Use connect method to connect to the server
    await client.connect();
    console.log('Connected successfully to server');
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    const collection = db.collection('documents');

    // the following code examples can be pasted here...

    return 'done.';
}

main()
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error)
    .finally(() => client.close());



Yes, this works. But I still don't understand why mine doesn't work.

Your code works fine on my machine but slightly changed.
I use  mongodb-legacy instead of mongodb.
   import pkg from 'mongodb-legacy';
   const { MongoClient } = pkg;
   var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";

  MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database created!");
  db.close();
  });

my package.json in  the root folder  is  below.
If you wanna try to install packages again
    {
  "name": "mongodb-new",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test mongodb  legacy",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "mongodb-legacy": "^5.0.0"
  }
}

  


If you mean the MongoDB Database Server service, yes, it's already started.

I switched from mongodb to mongodb-legacy package and now it works as it should. Thanks for your help!

If my post was helpful please vote it, thanks

I did upvote it, but I don't have 'enough reputation to cast a vote' so it's not visible.

Ok never mind, thanks again
